# Power function c++

Tags: c++, function

I have given the code below, I have tried to workout how the function works. I don't understand what happens when you enter the while loop. Does result get multiplied by the power of the value of x? Why does n get lower? I mainly don't understand what `result *=x;` does.

```
//power(x, n) raises integer x to the power n
//no negative powers
int power(int x, unsigned n)
{
    int result=1;
    while (n>0)
    {
        result *= x;
        --n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hint, the following lines are equivalent (in this context):

```
result *= x;
result = result * x;

--n;
n = n - 1;
```

So your function written as simply as possible:

```
int power(int base, int exponent) {
    int result = 1;
    while (exponent > 0) {
        result = result * base;
        exponent = exponent - 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You should have an easier time understanding it now.

Answer (score 0):

The `power` function of `(x,n)` is just multiply x by n times.

`result *= x;` means `result = results * x;`.

`while` loop make sure the `x` has been multiplied by `n` times.

`--n` means `n = n - 1`. If `n=0`, it means `x` has been multiplied by `n` times. Then, the loop ends.